# Reading from stdin with a system argv

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, file-descriptor

I am attempting to cat a CSV file into stdout and then pipe the printed output as input into a python program that also takes a system argument vector with 1 argument. I ran into an issue I think directly relates to how Python's fileinput.input() function reacts with regards to occupying the stdin file descriptor.

```
generic_user% cat my_data.csv | python3 my_script.py myarg1
```

Here is a sample Python program:

```
import sys, fileinput

def main(argv):
    print("The program doesn't even print this")
    data_list = []
    for line in fileinput.input():
        data_list.append(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

If I attempt to run this sample program with the above terminal command and no argument myarg1, the program is able to evaluate and parse the stdin for the data output from the CSV file.

If I run the program with the argument myarg1, it will end up throwing a FileNotFoundError directly related to myarg1 not existing as a file.

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myarg1'`

Would someone be able to explain in detail why this behavior takes place in Python and how to handle the logic such that a Python program can first handle stdin data before argv overwrites the stdin descriptor?

Comment: Where are you using sys.argv? And have you tried `generic_user% cat my_data.csv | python3 my_script.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You can read from the `stdin` directly:

```
import sys

def main(argv):
    print("The program doesn't even print this")
    data_list = []
    for line in iter(sys.stdin):
        data_list.append(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

You are trying to access a file which has not been yet created, hence `fileinput` cannot open it, but since you are piping the data you have no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is *by design*. The conceptors of `fileinput` thought that there were use cases where reading from stdin would be non sense and just provided a way to specifically add `stdin` to the list of files. According to the reference documentation:

> ```
> import fileinput
> for line in fileinput.input():
>     process(line)
> ```
>
> This iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:], defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty. **If a filename is '-', it is also replaced by sys.stdin**.

Just keep your code and use: `generic_user% cat my_data.csv | python3 my_script.py - myarg1`

to read stdin before `myarg1` file or if you want to read it after : `... python3 my_script.py myarg1 -`

Answer (score 0):

`fileinput` implements a pattern common for Unix utilities:

- If the utility is called with commandline arguments, they are files to read from.
- If it is called with no arguments, read from standard input.

So `fileinput` works exactly as intended. It is not clear what you are using commandline arguments for, but if you don't want to stop using `fileinput`, you should modify `sys.argv` before you invoke it.

```
some_keyword = sys.argv[1]
sys.argv = sys.argv[:1]      # Retain only argument 0, the command name

for line in fileinput.input():
    ...
```